# Rails fixtures and namespace model - ActiveRecord::Fixture::FixtureError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, minitest, fixtures

in an app I work on test suite is done with Minitest and fixtures and I faced such a problem, I can't solve, neither find a solution.

I have a model `Survey` and fixtures for it `test/fixtures/surveys.yml`:

```
one:
  user: admin
  name: Survey one
  description: This is survey one
  company: university
  review_type: 1

two:
  user: admin
  name: Survey two
  description: This is survey two
  company: university
```

also, I have namespace `surveys` and there a model for question - `Surveys::Question` (with polymorphic association), which has corresponding fixtures `test/fixtures/surveys/questions.yml`:

```
one:
  sentence: Survey question one?
  display_order: 1
  question_type: 0
  questionable: one (Survey)

two:
  sentence: Survey question two?
  display_order: 2
  question_type: 1
  questionable: one (Survey)
```

So far so good, things work. But whenever I try to add another `questions` definition to fixtures, let's say:

```
three:
  sentence: Survey question three?
  display_order: 3
  question_type: 2
  questionable: one (Survey)
```

an error is raised: `ActiveRecord::Fixture::FixtureError: table "surveys" has no column named "sentence"`

I totally can't follow up, why suddenly `ActiveRecord::Fixtures` fails to follow up.

I would be grateful for any suggestion on this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure your database schema has not changed and that you didn't remove or rename the column or table in your database.  Whenever you change your schema and run your migrations, be sure to run this before running your tests:

```
rake db:test:prepare
```

Then try running your tests again.  If you get the same error, it indicates your test database is missing that column.  Check your migrations to make sure.

Also, do you think maybe you need `three:` in `test/fixtures/surveys.yml` ?

Comment: That's amazing, as you suggested I added: `three:` in `test/fixtures/surveys.yml` and suddenly it worked. Perhaps, because of polymorphic association there need to be one on one coverage.